# Writing ISO to USB in CentOS

Tags: usb, dd

I've written many ISO images to USB in the past.  However, for some reason, I'm unable to complete this task on multiple machines running CentOS in my lab.

The scenario is fairly simple.  I have an ISO. The ISO itself was generated by a program in linux (rear - Relax and Recover).  It's bootable recovery ISO.

When I write this to USB using dd there are no(!) partitions being created.

For instance, I put this USB stick into a Windows machine and foramt it. I plop it into my linux machine and `fdisk /dev/sde` shows me the partitions.

`blkid` shows me the label and format type.

After excecuting `dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sde bs=1M` inspecting the partition shows me there are none.  The disk label has changed.

If I put use a Windows Utility, like rufus, and sure enough.  The partiton are there and the drive boots.

I'm somewhat stumped because I've never run into this situation before.  It's worth noting that the image is intended to boot a UEFI system. But I'm not sure if that matters in this case.

Comment: It looks a bit like the image is not a full disk but rather a partition only. Can you directly mount it without error (`mount image.iso /mnt`)? If you run `losetup -fP image.iso` then `losetup` you should see a loop device (e.g. `/dev/loop1`) with the image. Are there partitions shown (`/dev/loop1p1` and `p2`....)?

Comment: I think you nailed it. There are no partitions. So the ISO is just  parition itself.   Thanks for the direction. I wasn't expecting that.

Answer (score 0):

An ISO image is designed to be burned to optical media only by default. If it needs to be bootable when written to a USB stick, extra preparation steps are needed to enable that.

Modern Linux *installation* ISO images are almost always prepared in such a way, other ISOs usually aren't. Tools like `ReaR` may or may not do the extra preparation step.

For UEFI removable media, the requirement for bootability can be quite simple: if the file `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.efi` exists in a FAT32 (or ISO9660) filesystem, that filesystem will be UEFI-bootable on x86_64 hardware.

Technically UEFI-bootability on USB media might also require the bootloader file being located in a EFI System Partition with a correct partition type (0xef for MBR partitioning, a specific type GUID for GPT partitioning). But some UEFI firmwares are more relaxed and will boot from any removable media that contains `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.efi` in any filesystem that the firmware is capable of reading. A UEFI firmware will always support FAT32, and usually ISO9660, but may also optionally support other filesystem types like UDF or NTFS (PCs) or HFS+ (Apple computers).

Rufus may have simply created a valid partition table on teh USB and written the contents of the ISO into that partition, and relied on the operating systems and UEFI firmware being able to recognize and read ISO9660 filesystems. Or it may have been smart enough to have detected the `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.efi` file on the ISO9660 filesystem, created a separate ESP partition automatically, and copied the `\EFI` directory tree of the main ISO9660 filesystem into the ESP partition.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable insight.  That was really helpful in understanding the UEFI boot process.